# NSString to NSNumber : what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am executing this code:

```
NSLog(@"Converting line number %@ to int...",currentValue);

NSNumber * currentNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[currentValue integerValue]];

NSLog(@"Converted integer %d",currentNumber);
```

Which outputs this:

```
Converting line number 211 to int...
Converted integer 62549488
```

What am I doing wrong here ? In this case, currentValue is a NSMutableString with value of 211.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"currentNumber" is and object, which you're trying to print with %d.

```
NSLog(@"Converted integer %d", [currentNumber intValue]);
```

Comment: Or you could do `NSLog(@"Converted integer %@", currentNumber);`

Comment: Very rarely in iOS or Mac OS X's Cocoa do you work with primitive types. Everything is an object, and as such everything has getters and setters. NSNumber can be cast to float, int, double etc depending on what it is you want to get out of it (or what you put into it).

Comment: ExitToShell, that's absolutely not true. Very rarely do you abandon primitive types for objects unless the problem strictly requires it, or converting to objects helps solve a problem much more cleanly and easily. Primitive types are far faster, and generally, should be used when possible.

Answer (score 5):

Although your question has already been answered there is something else wrong with your code.

There are differences between Cocoa methods with `int` and `integer` in their names.

The ones with **int** such as `numberWithInt` or `intValue` deal with **int** s.

The ones with **integer** such as `numberWithInteger` or `integerValue` deal with **NSInteger** s.

This might be a source of errors and inconsistency when programming 32/64-bit programs.

Just something to be aware of and consistent with.

Answer (score 2):

NSNumber is inherited NSObject class.Its not an Integer.So you can use "%@" instead of %d.

You change your NSLog line as follows,

```
NSLog(@"Converted integer %@",currentNumber);
```